# How do I migrate vieys.py file without exceptions?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

when Im trying  to migrate my my .py file I'm facing an error  "^    if request.method == 'POST' SYNTAX ERROR : Invalid character in Identifier error"

this is my code

```
def register(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method() == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)
        # Check to see both forms are valid
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            # Save User Form to Database
            user = user_form.save()
            # Hash the password
            user.set_password(user.password)
            # Update with Hashed password
            user.save()
            # Now we deal with the extra in
            # Can't commit yet because we still need to manipulate
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            # Set One to One relationship between
            # UserForm and UserProfileInfoForm
            profile.user = user
            # Check if they provided a profile picture
            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                print('found it')
                # If yes, then grab it from the POST form reply
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']
                # Now save model
            profile.save()
            # Registration Successful!
            registered = True
        else:
            # One of the forms was invalid if this else gets called.
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)
    else:
        # Was not an HTTP post so we just render the forms as blank.
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()
    # This is the render and context dictionary to feed
    # back to the registration.html file page.
    return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html',{'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,'registered':registered})
```

Please help me with this , Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your mistake =

```
if request.method() == 'POST':
```

to =>

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Comment: Thanks..it worked.. previous I haven't used the brackets. But it still worked..